# How to enroll a student in Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I'm trying to create a button that will enroll a student in a classroom, and am getting a "Required path parameter courseId is missing" error, even though I have included that parameter. Disclaimer...my javascript is rusty, and this is the first time I've used the GC API.

Here is my code:

```
function joinClass(){

       try{
            var courseID = myCourseID;
            var enrollmentCode = myEnrollmentCode;
            var student = "me";
            student = gapi.client.classroom.courses.students.create(courseID, enrollmentCode,student);
            console.log("You have been enrolled!");
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: error says `courseId`, your code uses `courseID` .. could it be an issue with case-sensitivity?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, drudge. I tried matching the case, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Some more info from debugging attempts... the API slices the courseId into an array, then passes it to another function. That function returns "arrayForEach was called with a non array."

Comment: Some progress. student.create() is expecting an object, so this elminates the error:

`var joinObject = {courseId:"myCourseId", enrollmentCode:"myEnrollmentCode", student:"Me"};
                student = gapi.client.classroom.courses.students.create(joinObject);`

However, I am still not joined to the class.